# Representations of a group and its subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $(V, \pi)$ be a representation of $G$, where $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $\pi:V\to V$ is an automorphism.

Restricting this action to a subgroup $H$ of $G$, we get a representation of $H$, denoted by $(W,\theta)$.

I am wondering if there is some procedure to obtain the original representation $(G,\pi)$ from $(W, \theta)$ and $G$.

Comment: you should search around a bit the term induced representations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not (in general) : look at the restriction to the trivial subgroup.

Otherwise, a representation of a group $G$ in $V$ is not an automorphism $V\to V$, but a morphism $G\to Aut(V)$.